# Windows 10 JFileChooser

Tags: runtime-error, jfilechooser, windows-10

I recently got windows 10 and I'm having problems using the JFileChooser. Whenever the line with it runs it gives me this error "Qt: Untested Windows version 6.3 detected!" I'm not sure if anyone asked this but I tried looking and found nothing. The error doesn't tell me where it occurs. I feel this may be because of windows 10.

```
public class Load {
public static JFrame f = new JFrame(); 
/**
 * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
 */
public void frame(){

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Load Game");
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fileChooser.setApproveButtonText("Load");
    fileChooser.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    fileChooser.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    f.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);}}
```

Comment: Seems like the library isn't officially stable for win10. I think it has a version check in it (like in the manifest) which is not updated. think you have to wait for new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons:

1. you are not using properly JFileChooser component. Try:

   if( filechooser.showOpenDialog( frame ) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) { 
   ...
   }
2. A fresh Windows 10 does not have the proper UI params for JFileChooser class. Therefore try one (or both) of the following things:

   - a. download and install KBxxxx updates the windows 10
   - b. stop using `UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );` 
     in case you are using it and switch to default Look&Feel.